# Finding the limit of a $f(x)$ where $ \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x))=C$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $ f: [0,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ be a function of class $C^2$ (twice continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R$) such that

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)+f'(x)+f''(x))=C$$

Then prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=C$

My attempt:

Let us take the auxiliary function $g(x)$ defined as, $g(x) = e^x(f(x)+f'(x))$. Then we have $g'(x)=e^x(f(x)+ 2f'(x)+f''(x)$.

If we use Cauchy's MVT to the functions $g(x)$ and $e^x$ on any interval $[N, 2N]$, then there exists $\mathcal E \in (N, 2N)$ such that

$$ \frac{ g(2N)-g(N)}{e^{2N}-e^N}=\frac{g'(\mathcal E)}{e^{\mathcal E}}$$
$$ \implies \frac {e^{2N}(f(2N)+f'(2N))-e^N(f(N)+f'(N))}{e^{2N}-e^N}=\frac{e^{\mathcal E}(f(\mathcal E)+2f'(\mathcal E)+f''(\mathcal E))}{e^{\mathcal E}} $$
$$ \implies \frac {(f(2N)+f'(2N))-e^{-N}(f(N)+f'(N))}{1-e^{-N}}= f(\mathcal E)+2f'(\mathcal E)+f''(\mathcal E)$$

Now let us take the limit of $N$ as $N \to \infty$ (this also implies $\mathcal E \to \infty$),

$$  \implies \lim_{N \to \infty} {\frac {(f(2N)+f'(2N))-e^{-N}(f(N)+f'(N))}{1-e^{-N}}}= \lim_{\mathcal E \to \infty} {f(\mathcal E)+2f'(\mathcal E)+f''(\mathcal E)} \space \space \space \space \space \dots \space (1)$$

Now assume $\lim_{x \to \infty}{f(x)}=k$ and $ \lim_{x \to \infty} {f'(x)}=l$ and , then from $(1)$, we would have

$$ k+l=C+l$$
$$\implies k=C$$
So it shows  $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=C$.

I have a doubt regarding my proof. I had to assume that  $ \lim_{x \to \infty} {f'(x)}$ exists and is finite (This also deduces $\lim_{N \to \infty}{e^{-N}(f(N)+f'(N))}=0$) . Is it possible to proceed without that assumption? What are the modifications in this proof it would bring then?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71193/42969 and some Q&As on AoPS, all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20(f(x)%2Bf%27(x)%2Bf%27%27(x))%3DC%24&p=1)

Comment: The question is same. But I have doubt regarding my approach. That's why I'm asking. @Martin R

Comment: As you say, your proof assumes that $\lim_{x \to \infty} {f'(x)}$ exists and is finite. Given the structure of the other (working) proofs, I doubt that your proof can be fixed easily.